# Django template tag / jquery for- iteration?

Tags: jquery, django, templates, raty

Just a small problem i can't get my head around right now:

I have a list of objects presented in a table. One of the objects values is a score. I can use a Django template tag to show this as a number but i want to use my jquery plug-in to show stars instead. Not sure how to iterate over this. I'm trying this:

```
{% for result in mylist %}

<td>{{ result.type }}</td>
<td>{{ result.description }}</td>
<td>{{ result.rating.votes }}</td>

<td><div class="raty" data-number="{{ result.rating.score }}"></div></td>

{% endfor %}
```

And further down i got this:

```
<script>
$('.raty').raty({ readOnly: true, score: $('.raty').attr('value') });
</script>
```

The problem is that it shows the same score for every object with the jquery..

EDIT: I got it to work with this:

```
<script>
$('.raty').each(function() {
  $(this).raty({ readOnly: true, score: $(this).attr('data-number') });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

A `div` element does not have a `value` attribute. Try using a hidden input element. Something like this:

```
<table>
    {% for result in mylist %}
        <tr><td><input type='hidden' class='hidden_score' value='{{ result.rating.score }}'></input><div class="raty"></div></td></tr>
     {% endfor %}
</table>
```

And then in your script:

```
$.each($('.hidden_score'), function( index, value ) {
    var myval = $(this).val();
    $(this).parent().find( '.raty').raty({ readOnly:true, score:myval});
});
```

So, for each of elements having a class of hidden_score, you will get their value make a "raty" with the elemens belonging to the parent of each element (so they are siblings) with the correct score.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Nah this was not exactly what i was thinking of. Now i got an inputfield for each score and only the first one shows some stars (not right score but just "empty stars"). But i'll try to modify it and see what i get.

Comment: No wrong. The first field does show stars+ input field and the rest objects show inputfields with numbers in them..

Comment: oops I forgot to add type='hidden' to the input !

Comment: Yes that would make more sense :) But the problem is the iteration it's only showing the first objects value like stars.

Comment: Oops ! I haven't seen the {% for %}... Please check my updated answer !

Comment: Hehe ok. No it's not working but i think the $.each is something i'll look into. It feels like it's something with that..

Comment: Why not working? Try doing an alert(myval) to be sure that the correct value is shown each time. Also be sure that the correct ``.raty`` div can be found from ``find``...

Comment: Not sure why it didn't work but i managed do make a solution without the hidden field. Thanks for getting me in the right direction!