# Iterate over non jquery function/plugin

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, raty

I am not sure how to accomplish this, I've googled and search through stackoverflow but nothing, I did find [iterate over raty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764819/django-template-tag-jquery-for-iteration) but that wasn't really the same issue.

Here's my problem. I am using ajax to get an array from a php script that queries a MySQL database for result. Everything is straight forward there, it returns an array. below's the `rate.php` file. I then use `$.each` to iterate over the array the show in `div` what I would like to do is add the `.raty` rating system to each iteration.  Currently the rating system(stars) are added at the bottom/end of all the records not to each iteration. How can I accomplish this? Below are the codes

'rate.php' file that returns result in an array

```
    <?php
    require_once("../auth/config.class.php");
    require_once("../pages/request.class.php");


    $config = new Config;

    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $config-> dbhost . ";dbname=" . $config->dbname,  $config->dbuser, $config->dbpass);

    $request = new Request($dbh, $config);

    $rateme = $request->rateCare();

        echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.json_encode($rateme).')';
        //echo json_encode($rateme);
        //  var_dump($rateme);

    ?>
```

the html file that shows result
`rating.php`

```
    <?php

    $page_title = "IntelyCare: Rating ";
    //$page_description = "Description of this page";
    require_once    ("../template/header.php");
    ?>

    <body>



    <div data-role="page">
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function()
    {


         $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            cache:false,
            url: "../pages/rate.php",
            dataType:'jsonp',

            success: function(data){
                    $.each(data, function()
                    {

                        $('#care').append("Date: " + this.caredate + '<br/ >');
                        $('#care').append("Care Giver: " + this.fname + "  " + this.lname );
                        $('#care').append('<br />');
                        $('#care').append('<br />');

                        $('#star').raty({
                            starType: 'i',
                            hints: ['Poor', 'Ok', 'Good', 'Very Good', 'Excellent' ]    
                            });

                    });


                                }
                });

    });                 


            </script>
    <div data-role="header" >
        <h1>IntelyCare</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="main" data-theme="a" class="ui-content">
        <div data-role="content">
        <h3>Rate Caregiver</h3>
            <div id="care">

            </div>
            <div id="star"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Updated Working `Javascript`

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {   

         $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            cache:false,
            url: "../pages/rate.php",
            dataType:'jsonp',

            success: function(data){
                    $.each(data, function(id, obj)
                    {
                        divid= obj.id
                        para = $('<div id="'+ divid + ' ">'+'</div>');
                        $('#care').append("Date: " + obj.caredate + '<br/ >');
                        $('#care').append("Care Giver: " + obj.fname + "  " + obj.lname );
                        $('#care').append(para);
                        $('#care').append('<br />');
                        $('#care').append('<br />');                            
                        $(para).raty({
                            starType: 'i',
                            hints: ['Poor', 'Ok', 'Good', 'Very Good', 'Excellent' ]    
                            });

                      });   



                    }


                }); 
    });                 
    </script>
```

Comment: Are you sure the first part works? You are not returning valid json from your php script.

Comment: @jeroen yes, the first part works I am returning jsonp

Comment: It sounds like you want a `#star` element for everything you're appending to `#care`. You'll need to change your markup so that you're not calling `.raty` on the same element in each loop iteration.

Comment: that exactly what I want. `#star` element for each iteration. I am not sure I follow...can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Andre has right in the comment. You are always attach the `.raty` to the `#star`. Add a div with `id="rate{uniqueidhere}"` to the `#care`, append it before the 2 linebreaks, and attach the `.raty` to that newly added element.

Comment: I am not having any problems displaying the object, I want to display the `.raty` rating system for each iteration.

Comment: thx for the quick feedback, it seems like it's getting close but not there yet. I added a `var` `para = $('<div id="rate">'+'</div>');` and attached `.raty` to it `$('#rate').raty` it now shows up on the first iteration but not on all.

Comment: Because `id` attribute should always be unique! Add a unique id.

Comment: the `id` attribute `<div id="rate"></div>` rate is unique not used anywhere else. these are the 3 id's been used. `rate/star/care`

Comment: You say iterate. So you need `rate1`, `rate2`, `rate3`, in the `each` etc.. If you are always using `rate`, then when you say `$('#rate')` will be the last element with this id.

Comment: I am definitely doing something wrong and can't see it, I've attached my latest `javascript` can you make the changes there?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I got it to work, I had to move `.raty` back inside the iteration.